# Why have floats smaller headsep?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I am typesetting an illustrated  book, and the author pointed at the pictures seemint to have a smaller headheight. I think he is right and I am wondering why.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t]
\textbf{\framebox[70mm][r]{Example: headsep smaller }}
\end{figure}

\null
\vfill

\end{document}
```

And here is an image, that hopefully shows the problem:

[image: headsep_smaller_above_floats]

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't compare with normal text. Use a framebox instead if the \lipsum.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but why not? Is it bad typography to have the pictures at the same vertical position as the text?

Comment: Try it out and compare the positions.  A framebox has a rather large height and would change the position of normal text too.

Comment: if you want to see replace `\lipsum[3]` by `\fboxsep=0pt
\textbf{\framebox[70mm][r]{Example: headsep smaller }}` and add `showframe` package

Comment: Note that this ensures that, for a double-page spread, the lines of text on left and right pages will be aligned. Or, rather, it is a necessary though not sufficient condition for their alignment. If the top of box aligned with the top of the letters, this would not be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see nothing strange:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % just to show the head sep

\begin{document}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule height0pt depth0.2pt width 30cm}%
\lipsum[3]

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t]
\textbf{\framebox[70mm][r]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule height0pt depth0.2pt width 30cm}%
  Example: headsep smaller }}
\end{figure}

\null
\vfill

\end{document}
```

The two hairlines are at the same level, and the same can be said about the top rules produced by `fancyhdr` (used just by way of example).

[image]

What's happening, *really*?

The normal pages are subject to a feature called `\topskip`: the first baseline will be at `\topskip` distance from the upper edge of the text block. This doesn't happen with a float, where the first line will be flush with the upper edge of the allotted space.

A more significant example would be

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t]
  Nulla malesuada porttitor
\end{figure}

\null
\vfill

\end{document}
```

that would clearly show the situation.

I don't think this is a problem with floats, because they are a separate part and follow different rules.

If this is a concern, add

```
\vrule height\topskip width 0pt
```

to the first line.

Comment: can you try with just `\makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule height0pt depth0.2pt width 30cm}` as text and as object in figure?

Comment: @touhami Apples and oranges.

Comment: No I don't think so, with this you'll ses something strange (may be)

Comment: Thank you egreg! I compiled both examples and learned a lot (as always with tex.sx) – with "add ... to the first line" you meant: first line inside the figure?

Comment: As I already pointed ot, thank you very much, egreg. Yours as well as @Gustavos Mezzettis commands don't work for me at the moment. That may be because of my document, it's rather complex, so it will take some time to test it. Maybe I will figure out how to use the commands, then I will report here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I usually employ to cope with this situation:

```
\newcommand*\cleantop{%
    \dimen@ \baselineskip
    \advance \dimen@ -\topskip
    \prevdepth \dimen@
}
```

After this definition, I use `\cleantop` at the beggining of the floating environment, as I show in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\cleantop{%
    \dimen@ \baselineskip
    \advance \dimen@ -\topskip
    \prevdepth \dimen@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t]
    \cleantop
    Nulla malesuada porttitor
\end{figure}

\null
\vfill

\end{document}
```

Essentially the same as egreg’s suggestion.

Comment: As @egreg has already explained, the first box contributed to a page has `\topskip` glue above it, so that its baseline lies in a predetermined position.  But this glue is not added to the first line of an “internal” box, like the box into which a figure is set.  The `\cleantop` command emulates the `\topskip` glue in such “internal” boxes.  Its advantage over egreg’s `\vrule` is that it is somewhat easier to define a customized `figure` environment using this `\cleantop` command than using `\vrule`.